# How can I speed up a buffered WCF transfer

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, nettcpbinding

I am using a Buffered transferMode scheme in WCF to transfer a zipped file from a server to a client. The transfer occurs in a callback and the 3.7 megabyte files take just over 2 minutes to transfer.
Since I have a lot of other functionality working using this buffered mode, I would prefer not to change the scheme.

For reference here are the bindings I am using

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_MyIIService"
      closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      transactionFlow="false"
      transferMode="Buffered"
      transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      listenBacklog="10"
      maxBufferPoolSize="4967294"
      maxBufferSize="4967294"
      maxConnections="10"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="104857600"
             maxStringContentLength="104857600"
             maxArrayLength="104857600"
             maxBytesPerRead="104857600"
             maxNameTableCharCount="104857600"/>
      <reliableSession ordered="true"
             inactivityTimeout="20:00:10"
             enabled="true"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"
             protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I've already tried quite a few different variations for the sizes which do not seem to matter unless they are set to small.

In the callback on the server I am using the following snippet to send the binary (zip) files to the client. Here I convert the zip file into ASCII by using Base64 encoding. (By the way transferring the zip file as a binary takes the same time but arrives corrupted)

```
byte[] binaryData;
System.IO.FileStream inFile;
inFile = new System.IO.FileStream(path2ZipFile,
             System.IO.FileMode.Open,
             System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
binaryData = new Byte[inFile.Length];
            long bytesRead = inFile.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)inFile.Length);
inFile.Close();
string convertedToBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData, 0,
                           binaryData.Length);
handler(guest, zipFilename, convertedToBase64);
```

It takes about 15 seconds to drop a file on my Google Drive share. so what's up. How can I improve my transfer rate?

Comment: Are you accepting/returning a Stream parameter from your WCF methods?

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz that wouldn't be Buffered mode would it.

Comment: You are using .net (which is a managed memory environment). If you want to move about large blocks of data in .net you need to allocate large blocks of memory. If these blocks are dynamically grown/allocated then you will end up GCing and copying your data about a lot. I note that in most of your code you are passing in the length of your expected output. However I am not sure that is the case in some of the framework code. PLUS in you included code alone, you have at least 3 copies of the same data at the same time.

Comment: Sending files is always a pain the neck, as now you have to bump up your `maxStringContentLength` setting. You will also find the Base64 is actually bigger than the zipped version too.

Comment: @Aron I am using WCF to transfer a zipped file from a server 30 miles from here to my machine. I'm using netTcpbindings to do this. I don't think the problem is the memory size as I have buffers allocated that are more than big enough to handle the 3.7 mb. I am also not passing the length of my expected output. The length is used to convert the file from binary to base 64. This is actually fast enough. The bottleneck is in the actual transporting of the data. Thanks for your responses but I'm still looking for an answer.

Comment: It maybe worth bring up a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, you may find there is additional latency in your .net layer and the actual data transfer is fast, or you could find that your 3.7mb file is being serialized to a 10mb transfer.

Comment: I've used Wireshark quite a bit in the past but not sure how a session is going to help me. I'm sure there are layers of protocols to strip off but I can't see that this would be the bottleneck.

Comment: @Aron, So you might think that the protocol would take a ASCII file and serialize it before transfer?

Comment: You can get some statistics on the transfer, such as the size of the transfer and the transfer rate (by timing the first and last byte). If the actual transfer is fast and small, then obviously there is some processing latency on either/both sides. Divide and conquer, figure out WHERE your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

I you've tried everything else, you might give compression a go. In a nutshell, it takes a 1/2 second to compress the data on the host side, 1/2 second to decompress on the client side, but you reduce the overall payload sent over the wire by about 1/3.

You can either compress the byte() array before changing it to a string using System.Convert.ToBase64String or you can compress the base64 string before sending. Here's a little compression/decompress class for C#:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;

namespace CompressString
{
internal static class StringCompressor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Compresses the string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The text.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string CompressString(string text)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            gZipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        var compressedData = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
        memoryStream.Read(compressedData, 0, compressedData.Length);

        var gZipBuffer = new byte[compressedData.Length + 4];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(compressedData, 0, gZipBuffer, 4, compressedData.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gZipBuffer, 0, 4);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(gZipBuffer);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decompresses the string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="compressedText">The compressed text.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string DecompressString(string compressedText)
    {
        byte[] gZipBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedText);
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gZipBuffer, 0);
            memoryStream.Write(gZipBuffer, 4, gZipBuffer.Length - 4);

            var buffer = new byte[dataLength];

            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                gZipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Good luck to you. I've found this compression utility fast and easy to use. Of course, this code only works if you're using .NET on both ends. If you have an iOS or Android client, you would need to use a compression utility that's OS neutral.

Comment: Or just turn on compression on net.tcp if you are using .net 4.5. Also OP mentioned using net.tcp, thus .net.

Comment: @Brian - Yes I'm using .net 4.0 on both sides. Thanks so much for this example. I will try it out tomorrow when my time permits and I will get back to you. @ Aron, thanks for your suggestions

Comment: @Brian - Hi Brian, Today I used the routines you supplied to see if it would improve the transfer time. I want to say thank you. The class you suppiled worked flawlessly. However, the transfer rate was 2 min 19 sec for a 2,634 kb or 2.6 mb file. So to be honest, it did not improve the time one iota. But, it was fun to give it a try.  I just wonder how I can upload this same file to my Google Drive share in less than 15 seconds. So I'll keep searching. And please any other suggestions welcome at any time- Thanks

Comment: Rick, I can't imagine what the problem is. 2 Minutes for 2 MB is really slow. I've been working on industrial-size web services (WCF) fr more than a year and can easily deliver, from host to client, or client to host, 1 GB in < 2 minutes, and it's not the  WCF delivery that slows things down but rather the speed the database and fetch the binaries for me. So I'm not sure how to advise you.

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I think I'd try to eliminate every possibility. For instance, if you're running/testing over a network, I'd try running the client/host on the same computer, reading from one folder and writing to another, to eliminate the network as the possible bottleneck. If that didn't work, I'd try to isolate the next part of the delivery chain.  Good luck to you.